Empty edit in the suggested edit review queue
https://security.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/191692
I cannot find any differences in the renders, and the side-by-side markdown view just says "108 identical lines skipped" with nothing above or below it. The tags have no changes indicated and neither does the title. This does not appear to be an edit, yet the spam detection system is triggered and displays a "our system thinks this is spam!" warning above it.
What is this? Did the spam get cleaned up by another system or reviewer already but it was erroneously not cleared from the edit queue maybe?
I've voted to reject the edit because, if there is no change, then it is also not an improvement. Still, I am curious what is causing this state

I can't say for sure, but most likely the edit was to change i.stack.imgur.com image links to i.sstatic.net. The image consists of five image links, and the edit summary states it is updating five links.
As part of the image upload transition, the SE team retroactively changed earlier revisions of all posts and comments containing the former type of link to instead use the latter type of link. (You can confirm this fact by seeing really old posts from the 2010s "somehow" using the new URL scheme even in their earlier revisions.) This change would negate the edit, since the prior revision was rewritten to be identical to the suggested revision.

Sounds like that should be it! Odd, though, that the editor submitted this change while the migration was ongoing and then the migration caught up and made it an empty edit. What kind of timing is that?! What motivated them? Will we ever know??

When I first saw this edit request it had different links. But now the links are identical. So the original edit may have been edited by the original editor?
dunno

Not true. The 6-character check runs whenever a suggested edit is edited, and compares against the current non-suggested revision.
